# Rewriting domain only if not on local dev enviroment and forcing www with Mod Rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to write some mod rewrite code to redirect pages on a site to *always* use **www** and this has been working fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I now want to make sure this doesn't happen on my dev environment, which uses the `.local` domain extension...

So I changed it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.local$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does that seem correct?

As I understand it, it states: "If it doesn't END with `.local` AND it doesn't START with `www.` THEN do the RewriteRule"?

Comment: `Does that seem correct?` Does it work? Did you test it?

Comment: @yuri It seems to work locally, but I am unable to test it elsewhere yet; and even if it *did* work, that doesn't mean it's 100% correct code, hence my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! That is indeed correct. From the docs [for `RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

> ### '`ornext|OR`' (or next condition)
>
> Use this to combine rule conditions with a local OR instead of the
>   implicit AND.

The `[AND]` flag is the default behaviour of combining multiple conditions expressions together.

As for the rule itself, I'd suggest using `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `$1` in rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.local$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason you suggest using `%{REQUEST_URI}` over `$1` and why is the `^ ` portion of that last rule needed - seems pointless now?

Comment: Not much if it is being used from `.htaccess`, but at VHost level or server level config, `$1` will contain a leading `/`, causing rewrite to `<host>//<path>` (double `/` in URL)

Comment: Gotcha - cheers! :)